# How to perform convolutions individually per feature map

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have data in the format NHWC: `100 x 64 x 64 x 3`. I want to apply the laplacian filter to each channel separately. I want the output as `100 x 64 x 64 x 3`.

```
k = tf.reshape(tf.constant([[0, -1, 0], [-1, 4, -1], [0, -1, 0]], tf.float32), [3, 3, 1, 1])
```

I tried this, but this throws an error of dimensions. It expects 3 channels as input. 
    output = tf.abs(tf.nn.conv2d(input, k, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'))

I modified `k = tf.reshape(tf.constant([[0, -1, 0], [-1, 4, -1], [0, 1, 0]]*3, tf.float32), [3, 3, 3, 1])`, but this just outputs 1 feature map `100 x 64 x 64 x 1`. 
`

I tried using `tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d` but its throwing the same error. How do I actually implement it?

```
output = tf.abs(tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(input, k, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d` does. However, it is more general than that and actually let you choose one or more convolution kernels *per channel*.

If you want to have the same kernel for all channels, you need to duplicate the kernel to match the number of channels. E.g.

```
# my 2D conv kernel
k = tf.constant([[0, -1, 0], [-1, 4, -1], [0, 1, 0]], tf.float32)
# duplicate my kernel channel_in times
k = tf.tile(k[...,tf.newaxis], [1, 1, channel_in])[...,tf.newaxis]
# apply conv
tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(input, k, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
```